# How to find size (in MB) of dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

How to find size (in MB) of dataframe in pyspark ,

df=spark.read.json("/Filestore/tables/test.json")
 I want to find how the size of df or test.json

Comment: Does these answer your question? [How to estimate dataframe real size in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077432/how-to-estimate-dataframe-real-size-in-pyspark), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228138/how-to-find-pyspark-dataframe-memory-usage, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652767/pyspark-2-0-the-size-or-shape-of-a-dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the size or shape of a DataFrame in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652767/how-to-find-the-size-or-shape-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 11):

Late answer, but since google brought me here first I figure I'll add this answer based on the [comment by user @hiryu here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492463/compute-size-of-spark-dataframe-sizeestimator-gives-unexpected-results/49529028#comment114707562_49529028).

This is tested and working for me. This requires caching, so probably is best kept to notebook development.

```py
# Need to cache the table (and force the cache to happen)
df.cache()
df.count() # force caching

# need to access hidden parameters from the `SparkSession` and `DataFrame`
catalyst_plan = df._jdf.queryExecution().logical()
size_bytes = spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().executePlan(catalyst_plan).optimizedPlan().stats().sizeInBytes()

# always try to remember to free cached data once finished
df.unpersist()

print("Total table size: ", convert_size_bytes(size_bytes))
```

> You need to access the hidden `_jdf` and `_jSparkSession` variables. Since Python objects do not expose the needed attributes directly, they won't be shown by IntelliSense.

###### Bonus:

My `convert_size_bytes` function looks like:

```py
def convert_size_bytes(size_bytes):
    """
    Converts a size in bytes to a human readable string using SI units.
    """
    import math
    import sys

    if not isinstance(size_bytes, int):
        size_bytes = sys.getsizeof(size_bytes)

    if size_bytes == 0:
        return "0B"

    size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
    i = int(math.floor(math.log(size_bytes, 1024)))
    p = math.pow(1024, i)
    s = round(size_bytes / p, 2)
    return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[i])
```

Comment: I got the error: `py4j.Py4JException: Method executePlan([class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Filter]) does not exist`

I suggest using

```python
# Need to cache the table (and force the cache to happen)
    df.cache()
    nrows = df.count() # force caching
    
    # need to access hidden parameters from the `SparkSession` and `DataFrame`
    size_bytes = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator.estimate(df._jdf)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that something changed in PySpark internals. The code suggested by this answer doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

My running version

```py
# Need to cache the table (and force the cache to happen)
df.cache()
nrows = df.count() # force caching
    
# need to access hidden parameters from the `SparkSession` and `DataFrame`
size_bytes = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator.estimate(df._jdf)
```

Comment: this works, thank you... except the value I got back makes no sense. I guess the estimator can be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not easy. You can

- use `org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator`
- use an approach which involves caching, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529028/1138523
- use `df.inputfiles()` and use an other API to get the file size directly (I did so using Hadoop Filesystem API ([How to get file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167153/how-to-get-file-size)). Not that only works if the dataframe was not fitered/aggregated

Comment: This is Scala. The question asks about Python (PySpark).

Comment: would love to know if there is an equivalent of this method for pyspark, or find a pointer to where it is in the scala source code so we can see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, you can use Spark's [SizeEstimator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/SizeEstimator.html) in order to get the size of a DataFrame. But it seems to provide **inaccurate** results as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45223273/12982476) and in other SO topics.

You can use [RepartiPy](https://github.com/sakjung/repartipy) instead to get the accurate size of your DataFrame as follows:

```py
import repartipy

# Use this if you have enough (executor) memory to cache the whole DataFrame
# If you have NOT enough memory (i.e. too large DataFrame), use 'repartipy.SamplingSizeEstimator' instead.
with repartipy.SizeEstimator(spark=spark, df=df) as se:
    df_size_in_bytes = se.estimate()
```

RepartiPy leverages [L Co's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73707892/12982476) internally to calculate the in-memory size of your DataFrame.
Please see the [docs](https://github.com/sakjung/repartipy?tab=readme-ov-file#repartipy) for more details.